# Positive and negative terminal of a Tesla Coil

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, transformer

I'm trying to build a Tesla coil, I'm using it as a large voltage multiplier, though I can't figure out where is the output positive and negative terminal. thanks!

Comment: It doesn't have a positive and a negative. It has a high AC potential (topload, top of the secondary) and a ground (bottom of the secondary).

Comment: @Neil_UK Which means? sorry im bad at electrical circuits

Comment: Get better at electrical circuits before you attempt to build a Tesla Coil. Seriously, I can't even begin to explain the difference between AC and DC, positive and negative, before you've had electricity 101. Search for some really, really basic tutorials, ones that start with a battery, lamp, wires and switch.

Comment: @Neil_UK thank, I did spend to night looking through books and websites, though I still did not get the part that the coil as no positive or negative terminals, thank!